# One Save function rather than Insert and Update in my repository

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, automapper, repository-pattern

Is there any downside to having a save function that does both updating or inserting rather than using separate Update and Insert functions in my repos?

**Below is my save function in my CustomerRepository:**

```
// save
public void Save(Model.Customer customer)
{
    if (customer.Id == 0)
    {
        context.Customers.Add(Mapper.Map<Data.Customer>(customer));
    } 
    else
    {
        context.Entry(Mapper.Map<Data.Customer>(customer)).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: I use upsert in my repositories and never had a problem with it. I use a stored procedure to first insert a record into the table then grab the primary key and then do an update on the rest of the fields in the table, then return the primary key as the result of the stored procedure. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing wrong with this if that is the way you want to write it. As the code is so simple then it saves you writing two methods. Perhaps when you want to do more for either Save or Update it would be best to split it our into separate methods but that is your call.

The only downside to this could be that you are limiting yourself further down the line. Also for testing it makes it less clear. You could argue that single responsibility could apply here if you wanted to be really picky.

My personal preference would be to have separate methods that are unit tested so I know my code is bullet proof. If I introduce something that breaks the save but not the update it will be clear where I am going wrong. Writing each one separately isn't much extra work and could save headache later down the line.